# Java, Drawing on an JPanel with colors

Tags: java, user-interface, jpanel, drawing2d

I coded a program where you can insert coordinates and the size of an sqaure and draw it on a `JPanel`. I used:

```
panel.getGraphics().drawRect(x,y,h,b);
```

Now I want to add an color-chooser like that:

```
color Farbe = JColorChooser.showDialog(null, "Color-Chooser", null);
```

So now how do I draw the Square with color?  I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
panel.getGraphics().drawRect(x,y,h,b, Farbe);
```

Comment: Mistake #1 - Not formatting your code in the question; Mistake #2 - `panel.getGraphics()`

Answer (score 1):

`panel.getGraphics()` is NOT how custom painting should be performed.

See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

Start by creating a custom component that extends from something `JPanel`, override it's `paintComponent` method (and make sure you call `super.paintComponent` before you do any custom painting).

Place you "drawing" logic within it.  This panel should provide a setter and getter which allows external classes to change the color of the rectangle been draw, this way, when `paintComponent` is called, you can change the color of the `Graphics` context accordingly.

Also, take a look at [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) for more details about how painting is done

Don't forget to call `repaint` when the color is changed to encourage the panel to be repainted

Comment: While I agree with this answer, it doesn't really answer the question. Please add that `drawRect` doesn't have a colour parameter and that the OP needs to call `setColor`.

Comment: @11684 `drawRect` is a method of the `Graphics` object, through which you would also change the color

Comment: Change colour through `drawRect()`?! Let me check the docs again.

Comment: @11684 Not through `java.awt.Graphics`, you need to use one it's methods to change the color before you paint

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your last comment. I checked the docs: as far as I can tell there is no `Color` parameter here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawRect-int-int-int-int- . Also, I don't see any overloads.

Comment: @11684 That's right, you need to use one of the methods that `Graphics(2D)` provides to change the color of the graphics context BEFORE you try to painting to it.  In three links I've linked to, there are numerous examples